# After sending HTTP request to server sometimes I get status 302 (redirect)

Tags: android, http, post, curl

I try to send `POST` request to some server with json parameters and I wait json response.

From Android it works fine but from Linux I get status `302` redirect. I really don't know where is my problem.

Here is command from linux:

> curl  -i -X POST   --data "id=105&json={\"orderBy\":0\"maxResults\":50}"  "http://mysite.com/ctlClient/"

And I get response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 302 Found
 Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2013 12:22:06 GMT
 Server: Apache
 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.19
 Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dqblvijvttgsdrv2u5tn72p9d6; path=/
 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
 Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
 Pragma: no-cache
 location: http://mysite.com/fwf/online/
 Content-Length: 0
 Connection: close
 Content-Type: text/html
```

From Server `access log`:

> "POST /ctlClient/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5"

**Android:**

```
            String data = "{\"orderBy\":0\"maxResults\":50}";
        String WEFI_MAIL_URL = "http://mysite.com/ctlClient/";


        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
        String out = null;

        try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(WEFI_MAIL_URL);

            httpost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)");

            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "105"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", data));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line = null;
                while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    out = line;
                }
                is.close();

                if(isTimeOut == false){
                    _loadActual();
                }
                else{
                    return;
                }   
            } else {
                return;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {             
        }

        if (httpclient != null) {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }       
    }
```

`access log` on Android response:

```
 "POST /ctlClient/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)"
 "GET /fwf/online/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13981 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)"
```

We can see that on POST server redirects me to `/fwf/online/`

From Wireshark i get the same results from both methods:

```
POST /ctlClient/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1 (java 1.5)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 301
Host: mysite.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Why it works from Android but not from Linux with CURL?

**Can anybody help me or give me direction how can i solve it?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add -L to your curl command. See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_tell_curl_to_follow_HTT.